# Как изменить размер scrollbar css в Mozila?

Tags: html, css

У меня в css есть следующие строки:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 2px;
}
```

Всё корректно работает в Google Chrome, но в Mozila это не работает. Что нужно сделать, чтобы сработало?

Comment: При помощи CSS никак, Firefox его не поддерживает. Можете проверить на [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Мне очень жаль, но вам стоит поискать другой вариант решения вашей задачи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]